# installing jquery in ruby on rails, help

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

okay im still learning ruby on rails and it includes prototype when you do *rails new* but i use jquery, Ive been looking around and i saw people talking about https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails and to do some *gem 'jquery-rails'* and then some other stuff. Im not sure how to do any of this, can someone give me a step by step guide on how to install jquery on rails? im on windows. thank you!

ive seen 'tutorials' saying

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
bundle 
rails generate jquery:include
```

i've tried typing the gem command and it doesnt do anything, so i cant get passed that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to place line `gem 'jquery-rails'` in your `Gemfile`, not execute on the command line.

By the way, rails versions 3.1 (not yet released, but can be installed with `gem install rails --pre`) includes jQuery by default instead of prototype.

Comment: yeah i know that! but if i install rails 3.1 could stuff go wrong?

Comment: @user645607: yes, `bundle install`, then `rails generate jquery:install`

Comment: okay i tried bundle install but it had an error or something!

Comment: @Victor: you don't need to run jquery:install on Rails 3.1, assuming application.js is set up correctly.